# cannot @mention a user in chatter post - [User X] doesn't have access and won't see this update

Tags: chatter

I cannot @mention a user in chatter post, it shows a message like
`[User X] doesn't have access and won't see this update.`
@mention is greyed out when I add that user.
This is not happening for all users.

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000330305&type=1&mode=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000330305&type=1&mode=1), This issue occurs if the person being mentioned does not have access to the record that was just created.

To verify it, You can run a simple SOQL query using **UserRecordAccess** object:-

```
SELECT RecordId, HasEditAccess FROM UserRecordAccess WHERE UserId = [single ID] AND RecordId = [single ID]
```